# Split a phrase into multidimesional array of characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, char

I have a String that contains a phrase inputted by the user:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class eldertonguetranslator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputtext;
        System.out.println("Enter you text: ");
        inputtext = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Right now an example value of that string is:

```
lorem ipsum
```

How would I go about diving each word of that string into an array of individual characters?

So that is would be like this:

```
char[][] splittext = { {l, o , r, e, m}, {i, p, s, u, m} };
```

Remember that the number of words in the phrase, and how many letters are in that word will change every time.

Thank you all so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
char[][] wordsAsChars = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
  .map(String::toCharArray)
  .toArray(char[][]::new);
```

This [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) the words found by splitting the input on spaces, converting each word to its `char[]` equivalent, then collects the `char[]` into a `char[][]`.

[`String#split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) accepts a *regex* (in this case just a plain space character) and returns a `String[]`.

[`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D)) streams the elements of an array.

---

The reverse of the process, ie taking a `char[][]` and producing a sentence, is:

```
String sentence = Arrays.stream(wordsAsChars)
  .map(String::new)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

`.map(String::new)` invokes the [`String​(char[] value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D)) constructor.

[`joining(" ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)) joins all elements of a `String` stream, separating them with a space

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great! Just of out interest, could you explain in simple terms how this works? I like to try and learn how a piece of code works, rather than just copying and pasting it :)

Comment: You're a total legend dude! The explanation's great!

Comment: Follow up question: how would I go about reversing this? i.e. the output of [this](https://pastebin.com/zJrkQVMz) is the value of a string.

Comment: Do you mean converting a `char[][]` to a `String[]` or a single `String` of the sentence?

Comment: A single String of the sentence. Thank you so much for the continued help!

Comment: With the explanation and everything. You're the best!